# All video formats are incompatible with my android app

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play video in the app. Currently I am using Android Studio 3.4.2 and trying to run an app on an emulator.

When I create 'raw' directory and add video file to it, there is '?' at the place of icon and once I run the app I am getting **"can't play video"** message.

I have tried all formats `.mp4,.avi,.webm,.mkv and .ts`

but the problem continues.

Device I am using is:

- Pixel
- Android 10 Api 29

I have tried all video formats and even tried a YouTube link

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource//:" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo);

        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: `"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo` is not the right way to get the resource from raw directory. Get the resource's `Uri`, and then play the Uri. Also `.mp4,.avi,.webm,.mkv and .ts` are only the video containers, also the video codec matters.

Comment: how to change codec?

Comment: using some video coder app. Check the documentation about which codecs are supported by Android